# Unparseable date Exception java date pattern

Tags: java, date, parsing

I am facing an error trying to parse dates with this format:

26-March-2001
15-August-2001

I am using the next code:

```
    private void parseDate(String firstDate) {
        Date fDate = null;
        try {
            fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse(firstDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the error message: Unparseable date: "15-August-2001". I am not pretty sure what date format I have to use.

Thanks

Comment: try adding 4M (July/August) instead of 3M (Jul/Aug). so to get the full spelt out month, MMMM is what you are looking for

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Locale.US` so that it considers the month names in US format

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.US)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DaNZm3).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "15-August-2001" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
.toString()
```

Tip: Better to exchange date-time data textually using only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## *java.time*

The [Answer by Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57295321/642706), while technically correct, is outdated. The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the legacy date-time classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a custom formatting pattern with [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)). The formatting codes are not entirely the same as with the legacy `SimpleDateFormat` class, so be sure to study the Javadoc carefully.

Specify a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine the human language to use in translating the name of the month.

```
String input = "15-August-2001" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;

System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qHXcyA).

> ld.toString(): 2001-08-15

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]